# Touch events for Views on top of each other

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a layout where two views (in this case ImageButtons) are exactly on top of each other. Both should handle touch events to toggle the alpha of the buttons.

However only the button on top is receiving the touch event (but does not do anything since it's alpha is 0). The buttonBelow does not receive any Touch events when I press on the buttons.

The code i used to create the views and OnTouchListeners:

```
        // Create 2 Buttons on top of each other
        final ImageButton buttonBelow = new ImageButton(getActivity());//ImageButton
        buttonBelow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_locate);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonBelow.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        final ImageButton buttonAbove = new ImageButton(getActivity());//ImageButton
        buttonAbove.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_delete);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonAbove.setLayoutParams(params);
        buttonAbove.setAlpha(0.0f);

        root.addView(buttonBelow);
        root.addView(buttonAbove);

        buttonBelow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && v.getAlpha() > 0) {
                    Log.e("Button", "Pressed below");
                    buttonBelow.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    buttonAbove.setAlpha(1.0f);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        buttonAbove.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && v.getAlpha() > 0) {
                    Log.e("Button", "Pressed above");
                    buttonBelow.setAlpha(1.0f);
                    buttonAbove.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

How can the buttonBelow receive the touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class implement  View.OnTouchListenerYou, and use the same listener for the two buttoms, and then make your decisions inside that:

```
class YourClass implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        //...

           buttonBelow.setOnTouchListener(this);

           buttonAbove.setOnTouchListener(this);

        }

        //...

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (buttonBelow.getAlpha() > 0) {
              buttonBelow.setAlpha(0.0f);
              buttonAbove.setAlpha(1.0f);

            }
            else {
              buttonBelow.setAlpha(1.0f);
              buttonAbove.setAlpha(0.0f);

           }


         return true;
         }
     return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: Okay, that would work, I guess. But it's not possible to just pass down the touch event to the second button, because the top one blocks it? I thought that is what returning false in onTouch was for..

Comment: yes, if you return true that means that the event has been consumed, and false means that it has to be propagated to the next listener. that was going to be my first recommendation, but i saw that you actually was doing it correctly. Probably the system dont even consider the button bellow eligible to be called, you can check it out if you download android sources and debug it step by step. But anyways, making the class implement the listener and using the same function to handle all buttons on screen is a good, widely used, and even a preferable approach. So you can rely in it and feel ok!

Comment: Yep, just tried it and it works in this example. However in my "real" project I don't have references to my ImageButtons, I create them and create their TouchListeners elsewhere and don't know what Views are on top of each other.. I'll see if I can make this approach work with that problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can remove both the views(ImageButton) and add it again to relative layout in opposite order

Comment: But then I'm stuck with adding/removing views all the time. Surely it must be possible to pass on touch events to all the other views?!

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that because the `button above` is like blocking the one below
but you can make the on below the top one opposite of the top one using x and y

```
buttonAbove.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && v.getAlpha() > 0) {
                Log.e("Button", "Pressed above");
                int y = event.getY();
            int x = event.getX();
                buttonBelow.setAlpha(x);
                buttonAbove.setAlpha(y);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

or by making both in y but using if statement inside the touch click like this:

```
                if(y > 10)
                buttonBelow.setAlpha(y);
                buttonAbove.setAlpha(0);}
                else{
                buttonBelow.setAlpha(x);
                buttonAbove.setAlpha(y)
                  }
```

but the best using the one up there